# Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations: tensorflow/lite/kernels/reshape.cc:85 num_input_elements != num_output_elements (1200 != 0)

Tags: python, android, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a tflite model and the input signature of the TFLite model is 'shape_signature': array([   -1, 12000,     1]. I have tested with random data with shape [1,1200,1] and model runs without any error.

prediction shape is also (1,1200,1)

https://colab.research.google.com/gist/pjpratik/bd48804cc8d40239812079b5a249aac3/60367.ipynb#scrollTo=9qc4EpLTUw0v

Now I want to do this in android

I tried this in android but i'm getting this error

```
private fun applyModel() {
        val inputFloatArray = Array(1) { Array(inputAudioData.size) { FloatArray(1) } } //1,1200,1

        val outputFloatArray = inputFloatArray //Attempt 1
        val outputFloatArray = FloatArray(1200) //Attempt 2
        val outputFloatArray = FloatArray(1) //Attempt 3
        val outputFloatArray = Array(1) { Array(inputAudioData.size) { FloatArray(1) } } //Attempt 4

        Log.d("tflite", "Model input data: ${inputFloatArray.toString()}")

        tflite!!.run(inputFloatArray, outputFloatArray)

        Log.d("tflite", "Model output data: ${outputFloatArray.toString()}")
    }
```

````
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations: tensorflow/lite/kernels/reshape.cc:85 num_input_elements != num_output_elements (1200 != 0)
                                                                                                    Node number 6 (RESHAPE) failed to prepare.
                                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.allocateTensors(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.allocateTensorsIfNeeded(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:308)
                                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:248)
                                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.InterpreterImpl.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(InterpreterImpl.java:101)
                                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:77)
                                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.InterpreterImpl.run(InterpreterImpl.java:94)
                                                                                                        ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be much more kind of debugging, you need to check what kind of input your model is expecting and resulting what type of data.

You can try chunking your data and then try to work on part of the data, the below shows how I applied on dtln  `dtln_aec_128_1.tflite`

You can follow below implementation and can try to work it on your dataset

https://github.com/breizhn/DTLN-aec/tree/main/pretrained_models

```
private fun applyModel(data: ShortArray): ShortArray {
        val chunkSize = 257 // can be depending on your model test, can be 1200
        val outputData = ShortArray(chunkSize)

        val inputArray = Array(1) { Array(1) { FloatArray(chunkSize) } }

        for (i in 0 until chunkSize)
            inputArray[0][0][i] = data[i].toFloat()

        val outputArray = Array(1) { Array(1) { FloatArray(chunkSize) } }

        tflite!!.run(inputArray, outputArray)

        Log.d("tflite output", "Model direct output ${outputArray[0][0].joinToString(" ")}")


        val outBuffer = FloatArray(chunkSize)

        for (i in 0 until chunkSize)
            outBuffer[i] = (outputArray[0][0][i]).toFloat()

        for (i in 0 until chunkSize)
            outputData[i] = outBuffer[i].toInt()
        .toShort()

        return outputData
    }
```

For loading the model you can do this

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun loadModelFile(activity: Activity): MappedByteBuffer? {
        val fileDescriptor: AssetFileDescriptor = activity.assets.openFd("dtln_aec_128_1.tflite")
        val inputStream = FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)
        val fileChannel = inputStream.channel
        val startOffset = fileDescriptor.startOffset
        val declaredLength = fileDescriptor.declaredLength
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declared length)
    }
```

app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.12.0'
```

just below buildTypes{}

```
aaptOptions {
        noCompress "dtln_aec_128_1.tflite"
    }
```

and copied to assets folder